# Tab actions are not applied in my vscode editor

Tags: tabs, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Why tab actions don't work in vs-code? (the cause is not "tab moves focus(Ctrl + M)") - it doesn't get applied to. When tab is pressed once i get this msg at the bottom of editor "(Tab) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord". I guess it is linked to keyboard-shortcuts.

Comment: Yes, there must be a new shortcut added that uses Tab+something as the keybinding.  Search in your Keyboard Shortcuts for that by enabling the "Recording Keys" icon (the little keyboard on the right and press "Tab" and see if anything non-default shows up.  Probably an extension added something.